# Partial Matching in R getNodeSet

Tags: xml, r, xpath

This is more of a XPath question, but how do I tell getNodeSet to accept class matches on only 1 class?

For instance, I might have

```
<tr class="cool coolio">
```

and if I do

```
getNodeSet(root, "tr[@class="cool"])
```

I will not be able to catch the tag above, I need to fully qualify it with

`getNodeSet(root, "tr[@class="cool coolio"])`

Is there any way to catch the above tag without having to specify both possible classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this:

```
getNodeSet(root, "tr[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' cool ')]")
```